# ag-grid: Get double clicked row data within a multiple selection

Tags: javascript, ag-grid

in my grid I would like to have a multiple selection, but I want only the actually double clicked row to be used in a certain event. So, getSelectedRows() couldn't do the job (at least used alone).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Are you looking for the event rowDoubleClicked?

https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-events/

It's used like so:

```
gridOptions = {
    onRowDoubleClicked: doSomething
}

function doSomething(){
    alert('I did something')
}
```

The even will also pass the row data if you want to use that in the function:

```
gridOptions = {
    onRowDoubleClicked: doSomething
}

function doSomething(row){
    console.log(row);
    console.log(row.data);
}
```

Comment: Yes, I know I have to use it. But, how to get its data?

Comment: I think all the events will pass some sort of parameter to any function that you provide it. Events would be a little useless without it... When in doubt pass in a parameter and console.log it to see what if anything gets passed. I have edited the answer to show you what you can do.